# Use "with" with an R6 object

Tags: r, r6

I'm trying to use a construct such as "with" to allow easier (lazier ?) manipulation of an R6 object. Consider the following (minimal) example:

```
library(R6)
ToyClass<-R6Class(classname = "ToyClass",
                   public = list(
                     data=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(4,5,6)),
                     color = "red",
                     symbol = 16,
                     
                     initialize=function(mult){
                       self$data$x <- self$data * mult
                     }
                   )
)

foo <- ToyClass$new(2)
```

I can, obviously, plot the data in my object with

```
plot(foo$data$x,foo$data$y,col=foo$color,pch=foo$symbol)
```

However, being lazy (and since I have a lot of such objects to plot, so copy/paste/edit is time-consuming and prone to errors) I'd like to do

```
with(foo,
     plot(data$x,data$y,col=color,pch=symbol)
)
```

Which does not work:

```
Error in plot(data$x, data$y, col = color, pch = symbol) : 
  could not find function "plot"
```

I understand why (foo behaves as an environment, in which plot() is not defined), but I cannot find a solution. How can I look for function names, I presume, in the global environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add a `plot` method:

```
ToyClass2<-R6Class(classname = "ToyClass2",
                  public = list(
                    data=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(4,5,6)),
                    color = "red",
                    symbol = 16,
                    plot = function() {
                      plot(self$data$x,self$data$y,col=self$color,pch=self$symbol)
                    },
                    
                    initialize=function(mult){
                      self$data$x <- self$data * mult
                    }
                  )
)

foo2 <- ToyClass2$new(2)

plot(foo2)
```

If that's no good, another approach would be to set a parent environment as follows:

```
parent.env(foo) <- .GlobalEnv
with(foo, plot(data$x, data$y, col=color, pch=symbol))
parent.env(foo) <- emptyenv() # removes the parent environment
```

This can even be wrapped up in a function to get a more `with`-like feel:

```
with_global <- function(object, task_expr) {
  task_expr <- substitute(task_expr)
  parent.env(object) <- current_env()
  with(object, eval(task_expr))
}
with_global(foo, plot(data$x, data$y, col=color, pch=symbol))
```

Comment: Yes, this is true, and this is more or less what I have done - but as you may guess the real class is a complex animal, and my problem arose when I was trying to do a "non standard" plot, something like x/2 vs. y using type = "l". So I could have modified my plot method to accept "..." (in fact, it does) but then I had to plot an histogram, so I had to add an hist() method ... and then I needed another. .... etc.A never-ending work ! It is compounded by the fact that the init() method is in fact rather time-consuming, so re-generating a new variant of the object each time is ... long.

Comment: Ah right, I can understand a bit more now. I've updated my answer with a new solution using parent environments. Hopefully more helpful?